# Applying a function on each row of a data frame in R

Tags: r, filter, dataframe

I would like to apply some function on each row of a dataframe in R.

The function can return a single-row dataframe or nothing (I guess 'return ()' return nothing?).

I would like to apply this function on each of the rows of a given dataframe, and get the resulting dataframe (which is possibly shorter, i.e. has less rows, than the original one).

For example, if the original dataframe is something like:

```
id size name
1  100  dave
2  200  sarah
3  50   ben
```

And the function I'm using gets a row n the dataframe (i.e. a single-row dataframe), returns it as-is if the name rhymes with "brave", otherwise returns null, then the result should be:

```
id size name
1  100  dave
```

This example actually refers to filtering a dataframe, and I would love to get both an answer specific to this kind of task but also to a more general case when even the result of the helper function (the one that operates on a single row) may be an arbitrary data frame with a single row. Please note than even in the case of filtering, I would like to use some sophisticated logic (not something simple like `$size>100`, but a more complex condition that is checked by a function, let's say `boo(single_row_df)`.

P.s.
What I have done so far in these cases is to use `apply(df, MARGIN=1)` then `do.call(rbind ...)` but I think it give me some trouble when my dataframe only has a single row (I get `Error in do.call(rbind, filterd) : second argument must be a list`)

**UPDATE**

Following Stephen reply I did the following:

```
ranges.filter <- function(ranges,boo) {
    subset(x=ranges,subset=!any(boo[start:end]))
}
```

I then call `ranges.filter` with some ranges dataframe that looks like this:

```
start end
100   200
250   400
698   1520
1988  2147
...
```

and some boolean vector

```
(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,...)
```

I want to filter out any ranges that contain a TRUE value from the boolean vector. For example, the first range `100 .. 200` will be left in the data frame iff the boolean vector is `FALSE` in positions `100 .. 200`.

This seems to do the work, but I get a warning saying `numerical expression has 53 elements: only the first used`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to use `lapply` instead of `apply` to force the result to be a list.

```
> rhymesWithBrave <- function(x) substring(x,nchar(x)-2) =="ave"
> do.call(rbind,lapply(1:nrow(dfr),function(i,dfr)
+                      if(rhymesWithBrave(dfr[i,"name"])) dfr[i,] else NULL,
+                      dfr))
  id size name
1  1  100 dave
```

But in this case, `subset` would be more appropriate:

```
> subset(dfr,rhymesWithBrave(name))
  id size name
1  1  100 dave
```

If you want to perform additional transformations before returning the result, you can go back to the `lapply` approach above:

```
> add100tosize <- function(x) within(x,size <- size+100)
> do.call(rbind,lapply(1:nrow(dfr),function(i,dfr)
+                      if(rhymesWithBrave(dfr[i,"name"])) add100tosize(dfr[i,])
+                      else NULL,dfr))
  id size name
1  1  200 dave
```

Or, in this simple case, apply the function to the output of `subset`.

```
> add100tosize(subset(dfr,rhymesWithBrave(name)))
  id size name
1  1  200 dave
```

**UPDATE:**

To select rows that do not fall between start and end, you might construct a different function (note: when summing result of boolean/logical vectors, TRUE values are converted to 1s and FALSE values are converted to 0s)

```
test <- function(x)
  rowSums(mapply(function(start,end,x) x >= start & x <= end,
                 start=c(100,250,698,1988),
                 end=c(200,400,1520,2147))) == 0

subset(dfr,test(size))
```

Answer (score 4):

For the more general case of processing a dataframe, get the plyr package from CRAN and look at the ddply function, for example.

```
install.packages(plyr)
library(plyr)
help(ddply)
```

Does what you want without masses of fiddling.

For example...

```
> d
    x          y           z xx
1   1 0.68434946 0.643786918  8
2   2 0.64429292 0.231382912  5
3   3 0.15106083 0.307459540  3
4   4 0.65725669 0.553340712  5
5   5 0.02981373 0.736611949  4
6   6 0.83895251 0.845043443  4
7   7 0.22788855 0.606439470  4
8   8 0.88663285 0.048965094  9
9   9 0.44768780 0.009275935  9
10 10 0.23954606 0.356021488  4
```

We want to compute the mean and sd of x within groups defined by "xx":

```
> ddply(d,"xx",function(r){data.frame(mean=mean(r$x),sd=sd(r$x))})
  xx mean        sd
1  3  3.0        NA
2  4  7.0 2.1602469
3  5  3.0 1.4142136
4  8  1.0        NA
5  9  8.5 0.7071068
```

And it gracefully handles all the nasty edge cases that sometimes catch you out.

Comment: could you explain how to use it? AFAICT, it works on columns, not rows.

Comment: There's lots of documentation for plyr available from the help in the package itself or elsewhere. The ddply function takes a dataframe, a grouping variable, and a function; it splits the dataframe by the grouping variable and calls the function with each split. The result is then made back into a data frame.

Comment: the help is actually very short. how can I split the dataframe into rows? do I have to add a dummy column with unique id?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use `subset`:

```
subset(orig.df,grepl("ave",name))
```

The second argument evaluates to a logical expression that determines which rows are kept. You can make this expression use values from as many columns as you want, eg `grepl("ave",name) & size>50`