# How to apply a distribution function for each row in data frame

Tags: r

I know similar questions have been asked in this site [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236368/how-to-apply-a-function-to-every-row-of-a-matrix-or-a-data-frame-in-r), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650910/applying-a-function-on-each-row-of-a-data-frame-in-r), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330146/apply-a-function-to-each-row-in-a-data-frame-in-r), but none of them tackles my problem.

I've a data frame which I want to apply the `rdirichlet` function (from `gtools`) to each line. So, each line shall be consider as aplha.

```
data = NULL
data <- data.frame(rbind(
oct = c(60, 32, 8),
sep = c(53, 35, 12),
ago = c(54, 40, 6)
))
data <- data/100*1000

library(gtools) # contains the function


sim <- 10000 # simulation
```

My first attenpt was to use `apply`, it does work, but the output is not that clear for conducting further analysis; each row computation becomes a vector:

```
p = apply(data, 1, function(x) rdirichlet(sim, alpha =  x + 1))
```

I also try in a loop without success:

```
p = NULL
for(i in 1:length(data)) {
p[i] <- rdirichlet(sim, alpha = data[i] + 1)
}
```

Any tip how can I solve this?

Comment: Maybe `lapply(data, rdirichlet, n=sim)`

Comment: @jbaums, I guess you mean something like `sapply(t(data), rdirichlet, n = sim)` although it missing the `x + 1` part

Comment: @David - well that depends what a "line" is. (And I have no idea what the relevance of the `x+1` is... it's not described in the Q)

Comment: x + 1 is part of the code, since the function will need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two important things here. First, vectorizing is the best way to go:

```
ans <- apply(data, 1, function(x) rdirichlet(sim, alpha = x + 1))
```

By doing this, you'll receive each row computations as vector, essentially k vs sim like.

Then you'll need to subsample things like:

```
margin <- ans[1:100000,1] - ans[100001:200000,1]
```

Comment: Using `apply` isnt vectorizing. Not to mention this answer was already posted, and to mention OP was also trying using it

Answer (score 2):

Well firstly you might want to change the `data` in your anonymous function in the `apply` to `x` to match the `x` in `function(x)`

```
apply(data, 1, function(x) rdirichlet(sim, alpha = x + 1))
```

This works for me, as in it provides an output with three columns and 30000 rows.